# to insert line breaks in a file whenever a comma is encountered-Shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I need to write a shell script to re-format a file by inserting line breaks. The condition is that a line break should be inserted when we encounter comma in the file.

For example, if the file `delimiter.txt` contains:

> this, is a file, that should, be added, with a, line break, when we find, a comma.

The output should be:

```
this
is a file
that should
be added
with a
line break
when we find a
a comma.
```

Can this be done `grep` or `awk`?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd think `grep` might be an appropriate tool for this job. The name `grep` is derived from `g/re/p` which are the `ed` commands to search for an RE an print the matching line. That's all grep is for - searching for an RE and printing the result, it's not an editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/, /\n/g' your.file
```

Output:

```
this
is a file
that should
be added
with a
line break
when we find a
a comma.
```

---

Note: the syntax above will work only on system that have the `\n` as line delimiter as Linux and the most UNIXes.

If you need a portal solution in a a script then use the following expression that uses a literal new line instead of `\n`:

```
sed 's/,[[:space:]]/\
/g' your.file
```

Thanks @EdMorten for this advice.

Comment: i think it should be `sed 's/, /\\n/g' file_name`

Comment: what version of sed are you using? I'm using the gnu version.

Comment: Using `\n` in a sed script is non-portable, the portable way is to use a backslash followed by a literal newline so you script is on 2 lines, `sed 's/, /<backslash>` on the first line and `/g' file_name` on the second. You should change `, ` to `,[[:space:]]*` or equivalent too.

Comment: You need a backslash before that newline in the second one.

Answer (score 6):

This is what `tr` is for

```
$ tr ',' '\n' <<< 'this, is a file, that should, be added, with a, line break, when we find, a comma.'
this
 is a file
 that should
 be added
 with a
 line break
 when we find
 a comma.
```

Or if you must use awk:

```
awk '{gsub(", ", "\n", $0)}1' delimiter.txt
```

Comment: I guess the leading space is not desired

Comment: @hek2mgl : Not necessary, it can be removed

Answer (score 3):

Solution using awk:

```
awk 1 RS=", " file
this
is a file
that should
be added
with a
line break
when we find
a comma.
```

Comment: +1 but IMHO you should always state when a posted solution is specific to one version of awk and this one is GNU-awk specific courtesy of the multi-char setting of RS. I think you should make it RS=",[[:space:]]*" too so it strips any white space after a comma and also handles the case where there's no white space after the comma.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  Its not easy to know what version supporting what, but I will add this info to my mind.  Why not use `RS=", *"` instead of `RS=",[[:space:]]*"`

Comment: He might have a tab or some other white space after the comma instead of a blank charcater, IMHO you may as well take care of any/all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution using [perl](http://mdoc.su/o/perl):

```
perl -pe 's#,#\n#g'
```

Here's a sample of it working properly on OpenBSD or OS X:

```
% echo 'a,b,c,d,e' | perl -pe 's#,#\n#g'
a
b
c
d
e
%
```

E.g., unlike the sed solutions earlier, this perl works everywhere, because the same search/replace snippet wouldn't work with the BSD [sed](http://mdoc.su/o/sed) on OpenBSD or OS X:

```
% echo 'a,b,c,d,e' | sed -E 's#,#\n#g'
anbncndne
%
```